# COM export method from object in .exe application

Tags: c#, com

I want to export method from object located in running application using COM, but every tutorial i could find operates methods in .dll files.

Example:

I have a form and I want to access TextBox from another application:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
  public Form1()
  {
     InitializeComponent();
  }

  public int GetData()
  {
     return Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
  }
}
```

How can I export `GetData()` method so it can be called from another application? Is it possible to make it using COM?

UPD: that question still doesn't explain how to access an existing OBJECT through COM, not CLASS.

Comment: what is type of Your another application ?

Comment: I think it should be C++ DLL to make it easy to use for other developers